# Deleting old HDFS files is too slow

Tags: shell, hadoop, awk, hdfs

I want to delete hdfs on files two days ago, But the speed is too slow, can someone provide some optimization ideas?

**format**

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 nuomi-da-stat nuomi-da-stat          0 2016-11-15 11:58 /app/lbs/nuomi-da-stat/stat_platform_auto/943
```

**shell scripts**

```
hadoop fs -lsr /app/lbs/nuomi-da-stat/stat_platform_auto | awk '
  BEGIN {
    IFS="\t";
    n_days_ago=strftime("%F", systime()-2*24*3600)
  } {
    if (substr($1,1,1)=="-" && $6<n_days_ago) {print "hadoop fs -rmr", $8}
  }' | /bin/bash
```

Comment: Try to detect only the first file to start removing and from there to the EOF  print out the "records" (use a range pattern with AWK), then send the output to xargs with the -n option

Comment: @kcoder24 Thanks for your advice, I found the speed is due to hdfs file size is too large, now my approach is to create three linux background process to execute.